# apns server returns "invalid device token"

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I created two new certificates for iOS push notifications and exported the p12 files.
The iPhone retrieves the device token, and all seems to be ok, but the application server gets the apns response "token not expired"

The token i get is following (replaced with x here) 
97056623 0caedd1c 9c57a234 xxxxxxxx d7fa7236 xxxxxxxx 6160ee95 XXXXXXXX

ist that the correct format ? (except the "x" of course)

Comment: Are the spaces included in the token you are sending to the APNS server? They shouldn't be included. The token should only contain 64 hexadecimal characters.

Comment: Make sure you are using correct set of Profile and Certificates. Development profile with Dev. certificate for sending push and same goes for Production profile and certificate. This error is common and this is the most common solution for it.